# Differential equation - Laplace with Dirichlet condition on a rectangle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

In a rectangular domain $R$ with sides $a$ and $b$, with $b^2/a^2$ irrational, we look at the differential equation $- \Delta u = \lambda u$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions. How to show that the eigenvalues are given by $\lambda_{m,n} = \frac{m^2}{a^2} + \frac{n^2}{b^2}$ and the eigenfunctions are given by $u_{m,n}(x,y) = \sin (\frac{mx}{a}) \sin(\frac{ny}{b})$ where $u_{m,n}(x, y)$ is solution of the differential equation ?

I used the separation of variables : $u_{m,n}(x, y) = X(x)Y(y)$ and then :
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} - \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} = \lambda$$
Then we have
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = - \lambda - \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} $$
We assume that $\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = -k^2$. Donc $X(x) = \sin(kx)$
On the other side, we have
$$\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} = k^2 - \lambda.$$
It implies that $Y(y) = \sin(\sqrt{k^2-\lambda} y)$

With the Dirichlet conditions, $u_{m,n}(x, y) = X(x)Y(y) = 0$ if $x = 0$ or $a$, $y = 0$ or $b$.

Then for $X(x) = \sin(kx)$, $k = \frac{m \pi}{a}$ and for $Y(y) = \sin(\sqrt{k^2-\lambda} y)$, $\sqrt{k^2-\lambda} = n\pi$. It implies that $\lambda = k^2 - \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{b^2} = \frac{m^2 \pi^2}{a^2} - \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{b^2}. $
I don't know how i can delete $\pi^2$ from the solution...

After i have to show that $\mu (u_{m,n}) = mn$ where $\mu$ counts the number of nodal components in the rectangle. But how ?

Comment: the solution you're suggesting as the true answer, doesn't satisfy $x=a$ or $y=b$ boundary conditions! its argument need exactly the $\pi$ you're mentioning!